# Exibir div oculta de acordo o valor de um Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

Não tenho conhecimento de javascript e gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma div apareça de acordo com um valor de um capo dropdown.

Exemplo:  imagina um dropdown com valores de 1 a 10. se escolhermos uma nota < que 8 ele mostrar uma div

Comment: Oi Fabio, alguma das respostas respondeu à tua pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Coloca no CSS `display: none;` ou `opacity: 0;` para as divs estarem escondidas.

Depois junta um event handler ao `select` para ele detetar quando houver mudanças.
Depois na função que é corrida quando essa nota/`option` fôr escolhida tens de aplicar o CSS que faz com que essa div se mostre. E provavelmente vais querer esconder as outras que já tenhas selecionado antes, ou caso haja uma seleção errada.

Exemplo:

```
var notas = document.querySelectorAll('#notas div');
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var index = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    [].forEach.call(notas, function (div, i) {
        if (index == i) div.classList.add('mostrarNota');
        else div.classList.remove('mostrarNota');
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4bj50jga/

Comment: Ola só que minha intenção é só se a nota for menor que 8 fazer aparecer uma unica div. isso e um sistema de pesquisa se a primeira pergunta que e a nota for menor que 8 aparece uma div mostrando mais algumas perguntas

Answer (score 1):

Eu sugiro utilizar JQuery:

```
if ($("#ID_DO_DROPDOWN").val() > 8) {
  $("#ID_DA_DIV").show();
}
```

Comment: ola Amigo é essa a ideia, mais a div ta iniciando ja ativa

Comment: Ponha essa propriedade na sua div display:none;

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar [jQuery](http://jquery.com) para obter o `value` selecionado e realizar a comparação. Se o valor for `< 8`, mostra uma `div`, senão mostra outra ou oculta a mesma.
Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

Digamos que você possui um `input` para **CPF** e outr para **CNPJ**, e você quer mostrar de acordo com o valor selecionado.

```
    <body>
<select id='ddlPessoa'>
<option value="0">N/A</option>
<option value="7">CNPJ</option>
<option value="9">CPF</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none;' id='divCpf'>CPF<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' placeholder="CPF" />
    <br/>
</div>
    <div style='display:none;' id='divCnpj'>CNPJ<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' placeholder="CNPJ"/>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
```

Assim, basta obter o valor e mostra e/ou ocultar a `div` esolhida:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Chama o evento após selecionar um valor
    $('#ddlPessoa').on('change', function() {
        //Verifica se o valor é igual a 1 e mostra a divCnpj
      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
            $("#divCpf").hide();
        $("#divCnpj").show();
      }
        //Se o tempo for mé igual a 2 mostra a divCpf
      else if( this.value == '2')
      {
          $("#divCnpj").hide();
        $("#divCpf").show();
      }
        //Se não for nem 1 nem 2 esconde as duas
        else{
             $("#divCnpj").hide();
              $("#divCpf").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Chama o evento após selecionar um valor
    $('#ddlPessoa').on('change', function() {
        //Verifica se o valor é igual a 1 e mostra a divCnpj
      if ( this.value == '1')
      {
            $("#divCpf").hide();
        $("#divCnpj").show();
      }
        //Se o tempo for mé igual a 2 mostra a divCpf
      else if( this.value == '2')
      {
          $("#divCnpj").hide();
        $("#divCpf").show();
      }
        //Se não for nem 1 nem 2 esconde as duas
        else{
             $("#divCnpj").hide();
              $("#divCpf").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<select id='ddlPessoa'>
<option value="0">N/A</option>
<option value="1">CNPJ</option>
<option value="2">CPF</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none;' id='divCpf'>CPF<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' placeholder="CPF" />
    <br/>
</div>
    <div style='display:none;' id='divCnpj'>CNPJ<br/>&nbsp;
<br/>&nbsp;
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' placeholder="CNPJ"/>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/v4gNL/418/)