# Abrir div de acordo com a seleção de combo

Tags: html, div

Preciso incluir linhas em uma tabela com campos textbox de acordo com a seleção do combo.

O x é que se o usuário selecionar no combo Empregados = 2, deverá exibir os textbox Nome 1 e Nome 2, se selecionar Empregados = 3, exibe as linhas Nome 1, Nome 2 e Nome 3, e assim por diante, até o limite de 5.

Vi alguns posts mas sempre mostram 1 pra 1 (como: [Exibir div oculta de acordo o valor de um Dropdown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/77864/exibir-div-oculta-de-acordo-o-valor-de-um-dropdown))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //Chama o evento após selecionar um valor
    $('#DropEmpregados').on('change', function() {
    //Verifica a numeração do select no dropdown
      if ( this.value == '2')
      {
            $("#divNome1").show();
        $("#divNome2").show();
      } 
      else if( this.value == '3')
      {
          $("#divNome1").show();
          $("#divNome2").show();
          $("#divNome3").show();
      }
      else if (this.value == '4')
     {
          $("#divNome1").show();
          $("#divNome2").show();
          $("#divNome3").show();
          $("#divNome4").show();
     }
      else if (this.value == '5')
    {
          $("#divNome1").show();
          $("#divNome2").show();
          $("#divNome3").show();
          $("#divNome4").show();
          $("#divNome5").show();
    }
        //Se não for nenhuma das alternativas ele esconde todas
        else{
             $("#divNome1").hide();
             $("#divNome2").hide();
             $("#divNome3").hide();
             $("#divNome4").hide();
             $("#divNome5").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Pelo que eu entendi e baseando na lógica do exemplo do link, seria isso? Pode ser feito usando o script com css de várias maneiras...Mas acho que aquele exemplo que você deu o link já te deixou na cara do gol. Dá um retorno e um esclarecimento maior nessa dúvida caso não seja certamente isso

Comment: Daniel, 

A ideia é exatamente essa! Mas estou com dificuldade de fazer funcionar, pois todas as linhas com o nome estão aparecendo e nada de sumir.

Tentei colocar nas tags de tr o  style="display: none;", mas também não desapareceu.
Alguma ideia?

Comment: @mmooser tente utilizar DOM no style, talvez te ajude. Por exemplo:
document.getElementById("EditarClasse").style.display = "none"

Comment: @mmooser Se puder postar seu código, vai ser melhor de simular aqui a sua situação :)

Comment: Consegui! Tive que transformar a tabela inteira em div, pois os comandos relacionados à hide e show não funcionam com tabela (table, tr, td).
Muito obrigada!

Comment: @mmooser fico contente e poder ajudar, de nada! :D